# Вводится число N, N не превосходит 10.000. Необходимо вывести N открытых квадратных скобок [, после чего столько же закрытых

Tags: java, циклы

Пытаюсь решить это в Java...и что-то затупил с моментом вывода обратных скобок.
Никак не могу понять как сделать так чтобы количество "левых" скобок было равно количеству "правых" и соответствовало числу вводимому в консоли...
Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int n = in.nextInt(); n > 0; n--) {
                System.out.print("[");
            }
            for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
                System.out.print("]");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не сохранили переменную N. Второй цикл у вас вообще работает один раз. Надо просто сделать два одинаковых цикла.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print("]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно ещё с помощью рекурсии сделать.

Comment: Рекурси на 10тыщ вложений? Никакого смысла в этом нет.

Comment: Но ведь никто не запрещает.

Comment: stackoverflow запрещает

Comment: Во-первых, StackOverFlowError может произойти на глубине рекурсии в 10 тысяч только на самом древнем компьютере в мире. Во-вторых, что мешает прописать в VM Options -Xss10m, или -Xss100m? Не надо тут умничать.

Comment: Тут никто не умничает. Вам более опытные товарищи дают добрые советы и намекают, чтобы вы не давали дурных советов новичкам. Незачем делать рекурсивную реализацию алгоритмов нерекурсивной природы -- это **во всех отношениях** хуже, чем реализовывать их естественным образом, через итерации.

Comment: Ходить по улицам задом наперед тоже никто не запрещает, но вы ведь не будете учить этому своих детей?

Comment: Нет, ну если новичку не нужно знать про рекурсию, тогда ладно. В этом примере легче использовать циклы, а если у него будет более сложное задание?

Comment: Ладно, StackOverFlow может быть и на мощном компе.

Comment: Никто не запрещает также умножать или возводить в степень через рекурсию, но вряд ли вы этим занимаетесь.

Comment: Я и правда этим не занимаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд лучше сначала составить строку, а потому вывести ее целиком.

```
int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);      
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) sb.insert(0, "[").append("]");
System.out.println(sb);
```

Это быстрее, чем каждый раз выводить в консоль. но если Вам нужна еще более высокая производительность, то используйте массив. Это отработает еще быстрее:

```
int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
char[]ch = new char[n*2];
for (int i = 0; i < n*2; i++) {
    ch[i]= ']';
    ch[n*2-i-1]= '[';
}
System.out.println(new String(ch));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
char[] arr = new char[n * 2];
Arrays.fill(arr, 0, n, '[');
Arrays.fill(arr, n, n * 2, ']');
System.out.println(arr);
```